# 9p (libvirt/QEMU) share modes

Tags: virtualization, shared-folders, qemu

Can anybody explain what share modes - default, mapped, passthough, squashed - mean in libvirt/QEMU configuration?

[image]

I've got this share in `passthrough` mode. I see that inside VM it is owned by `vagrant:vagrant` user (which is absent from host machine) and share has rw bits set. But trying to create files there gives `access denied` error.

I need  to understand what is going on to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I once had a very similar problem, providing read-write access to the shared folder. It was possible to read files but I was not allowed to write files to the shared source path folder.

[Unix & Linux - KVM / QEMU / Virt-Manager : How can I store files in the mounted shared folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257372/how-can-i-store-files-in-the-mounted-shared-folder)

The root cause is that the guest system is running as `libvirt-qemu` user. What you should do to create files from within the running guest system in the mounted shared folder are these steps :

In `Virt-Manager` -> `Add Hardware` -> `Filesystem` select `Mapped` as `Mode` setting for the VM.

Change permissions for the shared folders : `sudo chmod -R 777 /<path-to-shared-folder>`

Change the owner to your username : `sudo chown -R user:user /<path-to-shared folder>`

Change the permissions for virtual disk files : `sudo chmod -R 777 /<path-to-virtual-disks>`

Change the owner to your username : `sudo chown -R user:user /<path-to-virtual-disks>`

Add your username to the `libvirtd` group : `sudo usermod -G libvirtd -a <your-user-name>`

Give full permissions to the `libvirt-qemu` user : `sudo setfacl -R -m u:libvirt-qemu:rwx /*`

Note : * = Specify the folder directory hierarchy you want to give `libvirt-qemu` the permissions.

Reboot the host operating systems ... now you should be able to create files in the guest system.

Information about 9p virtio -> [Sharing Host files with the Guest](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio) | [QEMU Documentation 9psetup](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup)

`Mode` specifies the security mode for accessing the source. `Mapped` specifies that the source is accessed with the permission settings of the hypervisor. `Passthrough` specifies that the source is accessed with the user's permission settings that are set from inside the virtual guest machine. This is the default mode. `Squash` is similar to `Passthrough`, the difference is that the failure of privileged operations like `chown` are ignored, this makes a `Passthrough` mode usable for users who are running the hypervisor without elevated privileges.

Comment: That shows a workaround, but doesn't explain the meaning of `Mapping` and friends.

Comment: That makes it more clear, thanks. I don't understand how `passthrough` could work, because I don't have this `vagrant:vagrant` user on host. What if I run `root` user inside guess - will it be able to access everything on host in `passthrough` mode just because name matches?

Comment: @anatolytechtonik : You can try it out ... but I assume that you want to run it as normal user, which is the safer way and the reason why I suggested the solution that worked without further problems in my case. :)

Comment: Before trying I'd like to understand how it should work.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik : The most relevant part is about giving the necessary permissions and the difference between the modes are explained. :)

Comment: `Mapped` mode is explained well, but I don't understand in `passthrough` how permission settings from inside VM control host filesystem.

Comment: Ok. I guess the question is too complicated, so I asked it here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/775104/how-does-passthrough-mode-work-in-9p-libvirt-qemu

Comment: @anatolytechtonik page not found

Comment: I think it's not really necessary to `chmod 777` on the folders, giving `libvirt-qemu` `rwx` permissions was sufficient for me.

Answer (score 8):

Share modes define how the virtualised (p9fs) file system is presented to the guest machine. There are important implications for permission mapping. To understand this, it's important to remember that the virtualised file system needs to manage permissions of files and they may not be the same in the host as they are in the guest.

The best docs I have found regarding the modes is from the [libvirt docs](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsFilesystems):

The filesystem block has an optional attribute `accessmode` which specifies the security mode for accessing the source (since 0.8.5). Currently this only works with `type='mount'` for the QEMU/KVM driver. The possible values are:

- `passthrough`
  The `source` is accessed with the permissions of the user inside the guest. This is the default `accessmode` if one is not specified. [More info](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2010-05/msg02673.html).  Beware that changes to permissions/ownership will affect all guests using that filesystem.  This mode is generally quite fast.
- `mapped`
  The source is accessed with the permissions of the hypervisor (QEMU process). [More info](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2010-05/msg02673.html). 
  This means you need to make sure that files on the hypervisor are accessible to the QEMU process (username `libvirt-qemu` on my setup).  The advantage is that file attributes and permissions are "mapped" for the guest so that they are independent changes elsewhere (as long as the files stay accessible).  If your host system supports ACLs, this mode will also allow proper ACL support in the guest.  This mode is generally a bit slower than passthrough.
- `squash`
  Similar to 'passthrough', the exception is that failure of privileged operations like 'chown' are ignored. This makes a passthrough-like mode usable for people who run the hypervisor as non-root. [More info](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2010-09/msg00121.html)

Comment: also note that passthrough mode does seem to have some issues with writing files, I have also encountered the issue listed here: https://serverfault.com/questions/559726/kvm-guest-cannot-write-to-9p-share-owned-by-non-root  Squash mode seems to work better