# Linux KVM: Make Mapped/Shared Folder Permissions RW for Host and Guest

Tags: permissions, kvm-virtualization

I am tearing my hair out trying to solve this permissions problem where files created by the guest cannot be accessed on the host.

**Setup:**

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 host and a Ubuntu 20.04 guest running through KVM. I have a shared mount setup in *mapped* mode. The host directory is `/home/user/VMs/shared/syncthing/` accessible through the guest vm at `/hostmount`. I am mounting from within the guest with `sudo mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L /hostmount /hostmount`. The guest VM is launched using virt-manager under the regular account `user`.

**Current Status:**

- The host can create files int the share which can be read and modified by the guest.
- The guest can create files in the share but they cannot be read or modified by the host user.

If I to a `touch /hostmount/test.file` from inside the guest as regular user `user`, on the host side I see the following permissions for `ls –l test.file`:

`-rw------- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm 0 Feb  4 02:51 /home/user/VMs/shared/syncthing/test.file`

**Desired Status:**

Of course, I could `chown` the file after creation, but how do I either:

- Force the guest VM to create files as `user` on host
- Grant `user` on host access to files created by guest vm (`libvirt-qemu` on host)

I have tried the suggestions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772784/9p-libvirt-qemu-share-modes). They work on pre-existing files but don't work for when the guest creates new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a the way to solve this in [this related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261618/setting-umask-of-libvirt-virt-manager-for-proper-permissions-in-a-directory-shar) though I'm guessing a more elegant solution exists. If you are running your vm from the command line, you simply add the `fmode` and `dmode` options to the command. For example: `--filesystem "/path/to/share","sharename",mode=mapped,fmode='0777',dmode='0777'`. This would make the directory world-writeable.

If you are using libvirt xml or virt-manager, you can delete your existing shared folder and add this xml right before the end of `<domain>`. Note that you may have to adjust some of these parameters, I don't know what they all do.

```
   <qemu:commandline>
        <qemu:arg value="-fsdev"/>
        <qemu:arg value="local,security_model=mapped,id=fsdev-fs0,path=/path/to/share,fmode=0777,dmode=0777"/>
        <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
        <qemu:arg value="virtio-9p-pci,id=fs0,fsdev=fsdev-fs0,mount_tag=sharename,bus=pci.1,addr=0x0"/>
      </qemu:commandline>
```

If you are on Ubuntu like me, you will also need to edit your `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu` and add the line `/path/to/share/{,**} rw,` to the end of it. This grants ALL guests access to this path.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, and your answer Mr. T inspired me, I think I found the more elegant solution: I went searching into the libvirt documentation to see if I could add those "fmode" and "dmode" option in the existing xml of my mapped mount instead of those custom qemu command instructions, and bingo, found and example here: 
https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#filesystems

So in my working solution, the first line of the xml of the mapped mount in virt-manager looks like, the rest unchanged:

```
<filesystem type="mount" accessmode="mapped" fmode="0770" dmode="0770">
```

In the host, I added my user to the group "libvirt-qemu" and logout-login to take effect. This satisfies my needs (editable directory from both sides).

I of course found tons of seemingly complicated solutions to reach the same goal, but I just have a basic use of virt-manager and this seems a good compromise to me.

For completeness, here is the full xml for the mapped mount. Maybe different permissions would be better, I don't know.

```
<filesystem type="mount" accessmode="mapped" fmode="0770" dmode="0770">
  <driver type="path" wrpolicy="immediate"/>
  <source dir="/host/path/to/shared/folder"/>
  <target dir="labelonguest"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x08" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</filesystem>
```

The second line was added by me from elsewhere, but I can't remember what "driver type" does. It shouldn't change anything.